# python3 ldap3 exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, ldap

всем привет , подскажите пожалуйста как правильно учесть исключения связанные с ошибками при использовании модуля ldap3

```
from pprint import pprint
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, NTLM, ALL, ALL_ATTRIBUTES

    def search(ip,bind_name, bind_pwd, search_base, search_filter, 
                    attrs=None):
        server = Server(f'ldap://{ip}', get_info=ALL)
        try:
            with Connection(server, bind_name, bind_pwd, auto_bind=True,) as conn:
                conn.search(search_base, search_filter, attributes=attrs)
                out = conn.entries
                return out
        except ldap3.core.exceptions as err:
            pprint (err)
```

выдает ошибку builtins.NameError: name 'ldap3' is not defined

Comment: А где ошибка произошла? На какой строке? Добавьте в вопрос трассу стека. ЗЫ, скорее всего у вас проблема в `ldap3.core.exceptions`, потому что вы делали импорт из ldap3, а не импорт его, поэтому идентификатора ldap3 не существует

Comment: похоже на то, а что тогда нужно импортировать и как вызывать исключения  чтобы был правильно?

Comment: Вам лучше знать что вы хотите импортировать :) Ну а чтобы не ругалось у вас так, то хотя бы `import ldap3`

Comment: `import ldap3` `except ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError as err:` работает, не могу разобраться как определить импорт, чтобы не весь модуль импортировать, подскажите?

Comment: Например: `from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError`, потом `except LDAPBindError as e`

Comment: работает, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение из `ldap3` было решено импортировать напрямую, минуя модули и вложенные модули:

```
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError
```

Тогда обработка исключения стало бы:

```
    except LDAPBindError as err:
```